# how to control outgoing intnet in android?

Tags: android, android-intent

is it possible to access and control all outgoing `intent` from my app?
i use some library in my project that sends `intent` to start other app (for ads) because that library is compiled i have no access to the source code.

i wonder if there is any way to block or control all intent sent by my app.

if you know any other way to prevent that app to start (ads) please tell me.

i think because my app start the other app, there is a way to stop it.

Comment: You might be able to use reflection on the library and hook the google API calls but you have to check the licensing scheme for the added library so that you do not do something illegal. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258562/rewriting-method-calls-within-compiled-java-classes

Comment: thanks, i will research in 'reflection'. right?

Comment: can i extends from that library's classes and @Override Starting intent method?

Comment: thank you so so mach 'mach' , yours truely, i appreciate. please answer so i can accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to use [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258562/rewriting-method-calls-within-compiled-java-classes) on the library and hook the google API calls but you have to check the licensing scheme for the added library so that you do not do something illegal.