# Is it possible to have Maven automatically rewrite a string in one of the class files?

Tags: java, maven

I am using a library, and one of the strings points to an API endpoint that is being shut down soon. I have been able to successfully go into the shaded jar, change the string value, and successfully run the application.

I cannot use reflection because this is being imported into a bigger system which reflection could cause some unpredictable insanity.

Is it possible to have Maven automatically change the value of the string when compiling this jar?

Comment: "this is being imported into a bigger system which reflection could cause some unpredictable insanity"

This is exactly what integration testing is for. If you make this change in the build process, rather than fixing it in code, you are decreasing the maintainability of your code and really just creating a band-aid solution.

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258562/rewriting-method-calls-within-compiled-java-classes

Comment: You don't have source code for the other library?